# How to add word-level features to Mallet SimpleTagger?

Tags: nlp, mallet

I have been going through [this blog post](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/project/cmt-40/Nice/Urdu-MT/code/Tools/POS/postagger/mallet_0.4/doc/simpleTaggerExample.html) which contains a SimpleTagger example.

It says:

Given an input file "sample" as follows:

```
CAPITAL Bill  noun
        slept non-noun
        here non-noun
where all but the last token on each line is a binary feature, and the last token on the line is the label name
```

**So, how do I add the word-level features here?**

Example: The number of syllables in the word, the length of the word, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything before the last token is treated as a feature. You should be able to add arbitrary features before this:

```
CAP SYL1 CHAR4 Bill noun
SYL3 CHAR9 responded non-noun
...
```